# Desktop duplication screen capturing - DuplicateOutput returns E_ACCESSDENIED error

Tags: visual-c++, directx-11, screen-capture, dxgi, desktop-duplication

I'm capturing the screens using desktop duplication APIs (DirectX11). The DuplicateOutput API returns the access denied error and that too happens very rare(may be 10% of the time) on a windows 8.1 machine on logon screen though my application is running with SYSTEM level privileges and the SetThreadDesktop being called properly. I used to reset and call SetThreadDesktop after every error I got but the application couldn't recover from the error after that even after multiple device resets and inits. I had to fallback to GDI (application works fine after being switched from directx to GDI) based approach after multiple retries or restart the application but that idea seems terrible.

Note: I did come across the same problem on Windows 10/ Windows 8 machines but not too often compared to that particular windows 8.1 machine.

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404600(v=vs.85).aspx) is the description of the E_ACCESSDENIED error that tells only possible case (not having system level privileges or the SetThreadDesktop not being called properly) for this error. I tried all the possible ways to find out the problem but couldn't.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Here is the code to init the device:

```
    //
// Initialize duplication interfaces
//
HRESULT cDuplicationManager::InitDupl(_In_ ID3D11Device* Device, _In_ IDXGIAdapter *_pAdapter, _In_ IDXGIOutput *_pOutput, _In_ UINT Output)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    if(!_pOutput || !_pAdapter || !Device)
    {
        return hr;
    }

    m_OutputNumber = Output;

    // Take a reference on the device
    m_Device = Device;
    m_Device->AddRef();

    _pOutput->GetDesc(&m_OutputDesc);
     // QI for Output 1
    IDXGIOutput1* DxgiOutput1 = nullptr;
    hr = _pOutput->QueryInterface(__uuidof(DxgiOutput1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiOutput1));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return ProcessFailure(nullptr, _T("Failed to QI for DxgiOutput1 in DUPLICATIONMANAGER"), _T("Error"), hr);
    }

    // Create desktop duplication
    hr = DxgiOutput1->DuplicateOutput(m_Device, &m_DeskDupl);

    DxgiOutput1->Release();
    DxgiOutput1 = nullptr;


    if (FAILED(hr) || !m_DeskDupl)
    {
        if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE)
        {
            return ProcessFailure(nullptr, _T("Maximum number of applications using Desktop Duplication API"), _T("Error"), hr);
        }

        return ProcessFailure(m_Device, _T("Failed to get duplicate output in DUPLICATIONMANAGER"), _T("Error"), hr);//, CreateDuplicationExpectedErrors);
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

The code to set the desktop to current thread:

```
    DWORD setCurrentInputDesktop()
{
    DWORD errorCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;


    HDESK currentInputDesktop = OpenInputDesktop(0, false, GENERIC_ALL);

    if(currentInputDesktop != NULL)
    {
        if(!SetThreadDesktop(currentInputDesktop))
        {
            errorCode = GetLastError();
            cout << ("setCurrentInputDesktop: SetThreadDesktop failed. Error code: ") << errorCode;
        }
        else
        {
            errorCode = ERROR_SUCCESS;

            cout << ("setCurrentInputDesktop: SetThreadDesktop succeeded.");
        }

        CloseDesktop(currentInputDesktop);
    }
    else
    {
        errorCode = GetLastError();

        cout << "setCurrentInputDesktop: OpenInputDesktop failed. Error code: " << errorCode;
    }

    return errorCode;
}
```

Here is the error message returned after processing the error code:

> Id3d11DuplicationManager::ProcessFailure - Error: Failed to get
>   duplicate output in DUPLICATIONMANAGER, Detail: Access is denied.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue eventually? If so, what is the solution?

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this issue ?